# How to Install a COM using ClickOnce

Tags: .net, com, activex, clickonce, teechart

I have installed my windows application that uses TeeChart ActiveX (a COM
Component for charting) using ClickOnce.

If I register manually TeeChart using regsvr32 teechart8.ocx, my
application works fine. But I want and I need to install the application using
ClickOnce.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ClickOnce can only copy files. So you have these options:

- Use Reg-Free COM as [Jeff Hall suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879788/how-to-install-a-com-using-clickonce/879819#879819). This is probably the best option if you can do it.
- Run `regsvr32` manually when your `.exe` file first loads (before it tries to access the COM objects)
- [Create a custom clickonce prerequisite package](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Add_Custom_Prerequisite.aspx) which installs the COM objects

Answer (score 4):

Use Reg-Free COM.  Check out this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188708.aspx)

Comment: The link is broken after many years of maintenance. If you could correct it that would be awesome. Still very useful.