# Moving from windows installer to ClickOnce deployment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, clickonce, dllregistration

We have a windows application. To deploy it we used windows installer. Now as our application require lots of automatic update we are thinking to move to winform clickonce deployment.

The only problem is we have some DLL in our project which require registration (vsdrfCOMRelativePath). How can I achieve the same in clickonce deployment

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Install a COM using ClickOnce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879788/how-to-install-a-com-using-clickonce)

Comment: What about switching to other installation system (NSIS, Inno Setup) which can handle this natively?

Comment: Here I'm trying to do the opposite because ClickOnce is a bag of bugs and users **will** get errors during install/update constantly.

Answer (score 0):

ClickOnce installs are for one user account, so will that be an issue? Services won't install either. ClickOnce isn't just another way of doing what an MSI install does, it is very different. You may be better off adding code to your app to call a web service and downloading the update rather than converting to ClickOnce. As far as I know, you can't run COM registration from ClickOnce. Make sure you understand all the ways in which MSI differs from ClickOnce!